# How to run Netbeans Java applet in TextPad

Tags: java, netbeans, textpad

I made a fuel cost calculator in the form of an applet in netbeans. Everything works just fine when I test it in Netbeans, but I need it to run in TextPad for my class. When I run the program I get different variations of this error:       package org.netbeans.lib.awextra does not exist. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Riley
 */
public class TGCApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    /**
     * Initializes the applet TGCApplet
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TGCApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TGCApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TGCApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TGCApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        StartingPoint = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        EndPoint = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Size = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        GasType = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        CostPerGallon = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Miles = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Submit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Clear = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        t2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        StartingPoint.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Minneapolis", "Madison", "Des Moines", "Bismarck", "Pierre", "Omaha" }));
        StartingPoint.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                StartingPointActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(StartingPoint, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 40, 110, -1));

        jLabel1.setText("Beginning Locations");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 20, -1, -1));

        jLabel2.setText("Destination Location");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 20, -1, -1));

        EndPoint.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Minneapolis", "Madison", "Des Moines", "Bismarck", "Pierre", "Omaha" }));
        EndPoint.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                EndPointActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(EndPoint, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 40, 100, -1));

        jLabel3.setText("Vehicle Size");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 110, -1, -1));

        Size.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Compact", "Mid Size", "Luxury", "SUV" }));
        Size.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SizeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Size, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 130, 110, -1));

        jLabel4.setText("Gas Type");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 110, -1, -1));

        GasType.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Leaded", "Unleaded", "Super Unleaded", "Diesel" }));
        getContentPane().add(GasType, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 130, 100, -1));

        jLabel5.setText("Cost Per Gallon");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 110, -1, -1));
        getContentPane().add(CostPerGallon, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 130, 90, -1));

        Miles.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                MilesActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Miles, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 40, 80, -1));

        jLabel6.setText("Miles");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 20, -1, -1));

        Submit.setText("Submit");
        Submit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SubmitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Submit, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 200, -1, -1));

        Clear.setText("Clear");
        Clear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ClearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Clear, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 200, -1, -1));

        jLabel7.setText("Custom Calculation");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 230, -1, -1));

        jLabel8.setText("Miles traveling.");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 250, 90, -1));
        getContentPane().add(t1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 270, 70, -1));

        t2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(t2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 270, 80, -1));

        jLabel9.setText("Cost per gallon");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 250, 80, -1));

        jLabel10.setText("Oil change cost (if any).");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 250, -1, -1));

        t3.setText("0.00");
        getContentPane().add(t3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 270, 60, -1));

        jLabel11.setText("Total");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(460, 300, -1, -1));

        t5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(t5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(430, 320, 90, -1));

        jButton1.setText("Calculate");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(330, 320, -1, -1));

        jLabel12.setText("Enter fuel tank capacity.");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 250, -1, -1));

        t4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(t4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 270, 80, -1));

        jButton2.setText("Clear");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 320, -1, -1));
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_SubmitActionPerformed
        if(StartingPoint == EndPoint){
            Miles.setText("0");
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SubmitActionPerformed

    private void StartingPointActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_StartingPointActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_StartingPointActionPerformed

    private void ClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_ClearActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_ClearActionPerformed

    private void MilesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_MilesActionPerformed


    }//GEN-LAST:event_MilesActionPerformed

    private void EndPointActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_EndPointActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_EndPointActionPerformed

    private void SizeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_SizeActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SizeActionPerformed

    private void t2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_t2ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_t2ActionPerformed

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        double a,b,c,d,e;
        a = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        b = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());
        c = Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());
        d = Double.parseDouble(t4.getText());
        e = ((a*b)/d)+c;
        t5.setText("$"+d);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    private void t5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_t5ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_t5ActionPerformed

    private void t4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_t4ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_t4ActionPerformed

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");
        t3.setText("");
        t4.setText("");
        t5.setText("");
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed


    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton Clear;
    private javax.swing.JTextField CostPerGallon;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> EndPoint;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> GasType;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Miles;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> Size;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> StartingPoint;
    private javax.swing.JButton Submit;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t5;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the file `java/modules/ext/AbsoluteLayout.jar` from your netbeans installation to the classpath. I am not sure exactly how TextPad handles classpath but from the command line it would be something like:

```
java -cp java/modules/ext/AbsoluteLayout.jar  -jar yourjar.jar
```